# findViewById() returns null on included layout?

Tags: java, android

I have an included layout in my activity's XML layout like so:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/info_button"
    android:id="@+id/config_from_template_info_btn"/>
```

I'm trying to set an `OnClickListener` for the button inside of that included layout by doing this:

```
findViewById(R.id.config_from_template_info_btn)
        .findViewById(R.id.info_btn)
        .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //Do things
    }
});
```

However, this crashes on runtime with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

The `info_btn.xml` layout simply contains Button widget like so:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/info_btn"
        ...
        />
</merge>
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: @Mett if you meant `setContentView()`, then nope, this code is directly after that call.

Comment: It'd be helpful to know which `findViewById()` is throwing the exception.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman it's the first one

Comment: I suspect the `<merge` tag is removing the outer layout, which is the one with that ID. Either just use one find on `info_btn`, or don't use merge.

Comment: You could use the Layoutinspector (Tools -> Layoutinspector) to find out if thats the case. (Remove the findViewById part for now)

Comment: @Mett yep, that does indeed appear to be what's happening

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman ok, I replaced the `<merge>` with a `<LinearLayout>` in `info_btn.xml` and it works! If you go ahead and write an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<merge.../>` tag is removing the outer layout, which is the one with that ID. That's the purpose of merge: to collapse unnecessary layouts for better performance. Yours is one common case. You need a top-level XML container to hold the included views, but you don't actually need view layout functionality.

Either just use one find on `info_btn`, or don't use merge. The only reason you'd need to do the double find is if you were including multiple layouts that each had views with an ID of `info_btn`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an included layout in your activity, you can access to the Button like if the button was inside the activity.

You only need to do:

```
findViewById(R.id.info_btn)
    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do things
        }
});
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is that I include the layout in multiple places, so I need to be able to set a different listener for each one individually

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do this:

```
findViewById(R.id.info_btn)
    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    //Do things
}
});
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is that I include the layout in multiple places, so I need to be able to set a different listener for each one individually

Comment: Then you need to set differents ids for each, it's not valid if you use the same component in one layout.

Answer (score 0):

Included layouts are added to your view already. You can do this way also.

```
findViewById(R.id.info_btn)
    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
});
```

Comment: If you included same layout in one layout multiple times then you need to define id for each.